# Is $f:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ differentiable?

Tags: functions, lebesgue-measure

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a nonempty compact set, and

$f:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the

$f(x) = |\{y \in \mathbb{R} \ | \ d(y,K) < x\}|$,

where $\displaystyle d(y,K)= \inf_{z \in K} |y-z|$, and $|\cdot|$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I know $f$ is continuous.

Is $f$ differentiable?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What does $f$ look like if $K=\{1,2\}$?